# Frequent FULL GC when reduceByKey

Tags: java, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I have a performance problem when running reduceByKey in spark, after open the GC log, I found that the problem happens on frequent FULL GC.

> 751.718: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 356320K->0K(1864192K)] [ParOldGen: 4890231K->5043998K(5592576K)] 5246551K->5043998K(7456768K), [Metaspace: 65608K->65608K(1107968K)], 11.6391872 secs] [Times: user=69.96 sys=0.09, real=11.64 secs] 
>   764.221: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 806098K->0K(1864192K)] [ParOldGen: 5043998K->5346213K(5592576K)] 5850097K->5346213K(7456768K), [Metaspace: 65608K->65608K(1107968K)], 21.0566545 secs] [Times: user=141.88 sys=0.29, real=21.05 secs] 
>   786.932: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 932352K->122871K(1864192K)] [ParOldGen: 5346213K->5592398K(5592576K)] 6278565K->5715270K(7456768K), [Metaspace: 65608K->65608K(1107968K)], 12.0117213 secs] [Times: user=69.77 sys=0.05, real=12.01 secs] 
>   800.961: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 932352K->335016K(1864192K)] [ParOldGen: 5592398K->5592312K(5592576K)] 6524750K->5927328K(7456768K), [Metaspace: 65889K->65889K(1110016K)], 22.2050083 secs] [Times: user=141.05 sys=0.27, real=22.20 secs]

I want to know:

1. Why there is no minor GC happens before FULL GC?
2. What happens when reduceByKey? What execution consumes memory?
3. What could I do to reduce the FULL GC?

Thanks a lot!